# Losing context when passing function from parent to child component's Input() property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, this

I am passing a `function` from my parent component, to my child component's `Input()` property.

The problem is, the parent's function is invoked in the child component, and the `this` keyword, now refers to the child component's context, instead of the parent components context.

Here is an example of what I am doing in my parent component:

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    next(continuationToken: string): Observable<CustomerSearchResult> {
        console.log('invoked');
        return this.customerService.searchCustomersPaged("andrew");
    }
}
```

In my parent component's template (I am passing the 'next' function through the input parameter named 'nextDelegate'):

```
<app-datatable [hidden]="!customersByFirstNameHasResults" [nextDelegate]="next" [serverSidePaging]="true" id="customersByFirstName" [showDeleteButton]="false" [showEditButton]="true" [responseModelObservable]="customersByFirstName"
      modelTypeName="customer" (editRow)="editCustomer($event)">
    </app-datatable>
```

And then finally, in my child component, I try and invoke the method passed in, but the `context` is wrong.

```
export class DatatableComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, OnInit {
  @Input() nextDelegate: (continuationToken: string) => Observable<CustomerSearchResult>;

private initializeDtOptions() {
// storing current class reference in a variable to use it in jQuery 

// function because we can't 
    //use arrow function as we might need both this' in the function
    if (this.serverSidePaging) {
      this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'simple',
        serverSide: true,
        processing: true,
        pageLength: 10,
        deferLoading: 100, //this.totalRecords
        ajax: (p, callback) => {
          //called here
          that.nextDelegate("").subscribe(x => {
            callback({

            })
          });

        }
      };
    } else {
      this.dtOptions = {
        pagingType: 'full_numbers',
        columns: this.columnSettings
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? I seriously think passing a function as an `@Input` is an anti-pattern. You could create an `@Output` property on your child component, and `emit` from there passing all the relevant data and have your function in your Parent Component that you wanted to call, behave as a handler to that event instead.

Comment: While it sounds like maybe structurally you're doing things in a way that goes against the Angular design pattern, what you're experiencing here is scope issues. MPJ has an excellent video tutorial on how .bind 'can re-point where .this' refers to. You'll find it at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GhbhD1HR5vk

Answer (score 1):

by context I think you mean scope. This is wrong because of how your function is defined.

Try using:

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
    public next = (continuationToken: string): Observable<CustomerSearchResult> => {
        console.log('invoked');
        return this.customerService.searchCustomersPaged("andrew");
    }
}
```

That said, this does seem to be a bit smelly. I would suggest using outputs, or injecting a service to handle this.